# How to parse a string until the end with Superpower in C#

Tags: c#, superpower

I'm trying to parse a string with Superpower in C#.

The following rules apply to the string to be valid:

1. It has to start with a letter
2. Only characters >= 0x20 and <= 0x7e are allowed
3. In addition, the following characters are not allowed: '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ';', ':', '(', ')'

I've created the following TextParser:

```
    public static TextParser<string> Name { get; } =
        from firstChar in Character.Letter
        from restOfString in Character.ExceptIn('{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ';', ':', '(', ')')
            .Where(c => c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7e)
            .Many()
        select new string(firstChar + new string(restOfString));
```

When I try this with the input string `"LC4711"` it works, but `"L{C4711"` returns `L` but I want it to fail, because `{` is an invalid character.

How can I implement this correctly?

Thank you for any help / advise!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing occurs because your parser successfully finds a letter at the beginning and then attempts to parse the rest of the string based on your conditions. When it encounters an invalid character (like {), it stops parsing further but doesn't fail; it just returns what it has successfully parsed so far.

to fix this you can do following:

```
using Superpower;
using Superpower.Parsers;

public static class CustomParsers
{
    public static TextParser<string> Name { get; } =
        from firstChar in Character.Letter
        from restOfString in Character.ExceptIn('{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ';', ':', '(', ')')
            .Where(c => c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7e)
            .Many()
        select new string(new[] { firstChar }.Concat(restOfString).ToArray());
}
```

Than in main or in any other class you are using your parser you can check whether it parsed or not by accesing the result

```
using Superpower;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "L{C4711";
        var result = CustomParsers.Name.TryParse(input);

        if (!result.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsing failed.");
        }
        else if (!result.Remainder.IsAtEnd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsing did not consume the entire input.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Parsed: {result.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

please note that the input is currently hardcoded to get a quick way of checking if it works in a new project where only superpower is installed...

you will need to change this so it matches your codebase or you can encapsulate the ifchecks in a separate method

Comment: Thank you, Jakub,
unfortunately this does not compile, since `Character.Letter.Once()` and `Character.End` cannot be resolved.
Do you know why?

Comment: @whaeussler Im sorry I missmatched superpower and another library it did not compile since the methods are not default to the superpower library I will edit my answer